# Results of the Feb 2013 Site Eval: what can we improve?

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

A few people have asked for the results of the recent "Site Eval" that was conducted through the new review(https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review) during the week of Feb 2 - Feb 9.  For some reason they're only available to mods at the moment, but a moderator from another site gave me a small script to extract and format the info below. (thanks Gilles)

In our previous "public" site eval, we were able to discuss and improve the questions that seemed to need some help, so perhaps we can do the same here.

`Ex Sa NI sc`

7  4  1  6   [Difference in nuance between 証明 and 証拠?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9727/difference-in-nuance-between-%e8%a8%bc%e6%98%8e-and-%e8%a8%bc%e6%8b%a0)

7  4  2  5   [How should I bid farewell to a superior?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/how-should-i-bid-farewell-to-a-superior)

5  5  1  4   [「こわいだから。」 versus 「こわい、だから[…]」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9764/%e3%80%8c%e3%81%93%e3%82%8f%e3%81%84%e3%81%a0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%80%82%e3%80%8d-versus-%e3%80%8c%e3%81%93%e3%82%8f%e3%81%84%e3%80%81%e3%81%a0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-%e3%80%8d)

5  7  1  4   [Is 以降 inclusive?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9671/is-%e4%bb%a5%e9%99%8d-inclusive)

4  6  0  4   [pronunciation and meaning of the word 干支崩年](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9749/pronunciation-and-meaning-of-the-word-%e5%b9%b2%e6%94%af%e5%b4%a9%e5%b9%b4)

4  5  0  4   [Why is 間 used to denote some amounts of time but not others?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/why-is-%e9%96%93%e3%81%8b%e3%82%93-used-to-denote-some-amounts-of-time-but-not-others)

3  6  2  1   [How do I express “to survive” in a more metaphorical sense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/how-do-i-express-to-survive-in-a-more-metaphorical-sense)

3  9  2  1   [How can I say “the leader(s) of the club” in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/how-can-i-say-the-leaders-of-the-club-in-japanese)

1  6  5 ‒4   [What is the function of と in とある?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/what-is-the-function-of-%e3%81%a8-in-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b)

0  5  3 ‒3   [Difference in nuance between polite requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/difference-in-nuance-between-polite-requests)

<sub>`Ex`/`Sa`/`NI`: number of “excellent/satisfactory/needs improvement” ratings</sub>

<sup>`sc`: total score</sup>

EDIT: I'm pulling out the more negative-tending and neutral questions for individual commentary.

Comment: Also, one big question I had but forgot to ask _during_ the evaluation is: What criteria are we supposed to use when evaluating quality relative to "other resources"?  Are we restricting ourselves to English-only, or English and Japanese (single-language resources), or resources that contain both English/Japanese?

Comment: @Troyen: I would argue that we should compare to the language of the question, so restricting to English sources for these questions

Comment: Also also, on the next evaluation, should we refrain from modifying questions during the eval itself to try and avoid interfering with the scoring?  It seemed like the first time there was cleanup during the eval, so I assumed it was okay this time, but then found out some people on other sites discourage modification until after the eval.

Comment: I'll talk about that with the community mods before the next one, to see if they have any technical solution/approach in mind. Note that the next one is not scheduled until early May.

Comment: I've featured this and added a call to action in the title.  We need people to explain *what* needs improvement.  For example, how can [*How can I say “the leader(s) of the club” in Japanese*](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/how-can-i-say-the-leaders-of-the-club-in-japanese) be improved?

Answer (score 1):

#### Difference in nuance between polite requests

- Satisfactory: 5
- Needs Improvement: 3
- Total Score: -3

Comment: I see basically two problems with this question. The first is that the title needs fixing, it's very hard to tell what the question is actually about.(EDIT: thanks to whoever changed it) The second is that there is quite a bit of discussion in the comments that should have been alternative answers.

Answer (score 0):

### What is the function of と in とある?

- Satisfactory: 6
- Needs Improvement: 5
- Total Score: -4

This question was [edited](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/9847/revisions) during the evaluation.

EDIT: oops... if I'm going to helpfully list the votes, it would help if I'd get the vote count right

Comment: I remember my NI vote here was from there not being a full answer to the question, so there was no way it was "better than other resources available". I suspect the negative score on "difference in nuance" is likewise due to the scope of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I express “to survive” in a more metaphorical sense?

- Excellent: 3
- Satisfactory: 6
- Needs Improvement: 2
- Total Score: 1

This question was [edited](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/9677/revisions) during the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I say “the leader(s) of the club” in Japanese

- Excellent: 3
- Satisfactory: 9
- Needs Improvement: 2
- Total Score: 1

Comment: I actually think this one was "almost there", but the primary answer got a bit wishy-washy at the end.  It ends up suggesting any of three options without really clarifying the difference between them, though it does more heavily recommend using 長.  If alternatives are going to be brought up, I think it'd be better to also explain why you would use them over 長.